# Anglesharp IElement save and load

Tags: c#, anglesharp

Is there any way to save and/or load a single iElement in Anglesharp?

Save somewhere:

```
        var document = parser.Parse(StrHTML);

        AngleSharp.Dom.IHtmlCollection<AngleSharp.Dom.IElement> LiItems= document.QuerySelectorAll("li");
        foreach (var Art in LiItems)
        {
            <here i want to store Art somewhere>
        }
```

After that i'd like to load and recreate IElement.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize an element by reading its `OuterHtml` property. It'll include complete HTML code of the element.

You can deserialize the string back into the element by using `HtmlParser.ParseFragment`. It'll return a list of `INode` containing one node which is `IElement` (`HtmlListItemElement` in your case).

Comment: Thank you @Squidward, can you please add an example for your deserialize answer?